# Why does dplyr::distinct behave like this for grouped data frames

Tags: r, dplyr

My question involves the `distinct` function from `dplyr`.

First, set up the data:

```
set.seed(0)

df <- data.frame(
    x = sample(10, 100, rep = TRUE),
    y = sample(10, 100, rep = TRUE)
)
```

Consider the following two uses of `distinct`.

```
df %>%
    group_by(x) %>%
    distinct()

df %>%
    group_by(x) %>%
    distinct(y)
```

The first produces a different result to the second. As far as I can tell, the first set of operations finds "All distinct values of `x`, and return first value of `y`", where as the second finds "For each value of `x`, find all distinct values of `y`".

Why should this be so when

```
df %>%
    distinct(x, y)

df %>% distinct()
```

produce the same result?

EDIT: It looks like this is a known bug already: https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/1110

Comment: FYI, it appears that this has been fixed. All 4 examples return the same thing for me, which is what I expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the answer is that `distinct` considers grouping columns when determining distinctness, which to me seems inconsistent with how the rest of `dplyr` works.

Thus:

```
df %>%
group_by(x) %>%
distinct()
```

Group by `x`, find values that are distinct in `x`(!). This seems to be a bug.

However:

```
df %>%
group_by(x) %>%
distinct(y)
```

Group by `x`, find values that are distinct in `y` given `x`. This is equivalent to either of these cases:

```
df %>%
distinct(x, y)

df %>% distinct()
```

Both find distinct values in x and y.

The take-home message seems to be: Don't use grouping and `distinct`. Just use the relevant column names as arguments in `distinct`.

Comment: so, this is a bug right? since it is incompatible with the helpfile for group_by: `The group_by function takes an existing tbl and converts it into a grouped tbl where operations are performed "by group". `

Comment: I think so. I hadn't noticed this behavior until you pointed it out, and it seems inconsistent with expected behavior of `group_by()` to me.

Comment: I think you have described the first operation `df %>%
group_by(x) %>%
distinct()` incorrectly. It should be "find distinct values in `x`".

Comment: Yes, I just edited the answer. It's probably best not to mix `group_by()` and `distinct()`.